# http post data: endpoint json parsing losing value for kotlin data class field with default value

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, axios, jackson

I have a Kotlin data class 'Category' with defaulted fields

```
data class Category(
    ...some fields,
    val type: String = "value",
    ...some other fields
```

I use axios to post a change with a json

```
{
 ... some fields,
 "type":"group",
 ... some other fields
}
```

The endpoint is:

```
@PostMapping("/{id}",
    consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE],
    produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
fun saveCategory(@RequestBody toUpdate: Category): ResponseEntity<Category> {
    return  ResponseEntity.ok(categoryService.save(toUpdate))
}
```

**The problem is toUpdate.type is "value" but that's not the value passed, it's the default value, the value passed is "group", why is the default value overriding the passed in value?**

How do I fix this?

BTW, When I use:

```
@PostMapping("/{id}",
        consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE],
        produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun saveCategory(@RequestBody rawJson: String): ResponseEntity<Category> {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(categoryService.save(jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(rawJson, Category::class.java)))
    }
```

**I can see rawJson has the field 'type' as 'group' which is as expected. So that approach works but as you can see much less than ideal.**

Comment: Maybe you could try using this annotation instead: @DefaultValue("value")

Comment: In order to support default fields the object mapper needs to have the kotlin module loaded, so maybe the spring boot default one doesn't load it (whereas your second example explicitely loads it), you could try manually adding a bean for ObjectMapper which loads it to see if that changes something.